# Using dynamic content in Wordpress by decoding and using a JWT passed on the URL, without logging in any user

Tags: wordpress, security, authentication, static-content, user-generated-content

I have a Wordpress and I don't want to create users for the next functionality:

I need a page that has this behaviour:

```
URL1 = https://my-site.example.com/some-page/ => Renders some public content
URL2 = https://my-site.example.com/some-page/?token=abc-payload => Renders private content for person abc
URL3 = https://my-site.example.com/some-page/?token=xyz-payload => Renders private content for person xyz
```

`abc-payload` and `xyz-payload` could be some sort of JWT that contains the user name, some sort of short private data, and a signature so the wordpress know this information is validly signed and displayable on the page.

Example:

Calling URL1 https://my-site.example.com/some-page/ it could render:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Welcome to the raffle             |
| - Sign up here                    |
|   - Name:  [         ]            |
|   - Email: [         ]            |
|            [submit]               |
+-----------------------------------+
```

And this form would NOT write anything into the wordpress but send information to a 3rd party system.

Calling URL2 https://my-site.example.com/some-page/?token=abc-payload it could render:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Welcome to the raffle             |
| - Welcome Alice                   |
| - Your inscription id is 33       |
+-----------------------------------+
```

In this case `abc-payload` contains `{"name":"Alice","id":33}` signed by someone trusted by wordpress.

Calling URL3 https://my-site.example.com/some-page/?token=xyz-payload it could render:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Welcome to the raffle             |
| - Welcome Bob                     |
| - Your inscription id is 77       |
+-----------------------------------+
```

In this case `xyz-payload` contains `{"name":"Bob","id":77}` signed by someone trusted by wordpress.

- In no case any of the wordpress tables are written or read to save or retrieve the data.
- No "wordpress users" are created.

## Question

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I came to the solution by myself. I'm sharing it here just in case it helps others.

First of all I installed 2 plugins:

[image: Plugins]

Plugin 1 is Block Visibility, by Nick Diego. This will allow me to very easily switch what blocks are shown to the user in function of if the `token` parameter is passed or not in the query string.

Plugin 2 is Code Snippets, by Code Snippets Pro. This will allow me to insert PHP code without touching the filesystem.

## Block Visibility

First, let's configure a "rule" that will allow the plugin to see if there's the token present.

In the page-editor click the menu at the top-right and find the option "Visibility Presets".

[image: Visbility presets menu]

Add a new preset, and do this:

[image: Configure the "token exists preset"]

1. Create a new preset
2. Set the name to "Token exists"
3. Create a Control Set and open the menu to select the type
4. Select the filter as type = "Query String"
5. Set that the query string you want is named "token" (or whatever URL parameter you want).

Save.

Okey, but WordPress won't recognize that parameter unless we instruct to. Here it comes handy the Code Snippets plugin.

## The Code Snippets Plugin

Once active, the "Code Snippets" plugin will add you a new option on the left menu. Click on it.

[image: Menu Code Snippets]

There are 2 types of Code Snippets written in PHP that this plugin handles:

- Functions, which are raw PHP code used for all the WordPress callbacks (like creating plugins on the fly)
- Content, which is HTML where we can open PHP tags to paint things on screen.

At the end of this example we'll end up having 3 snippets:

1. One function to add the `token` query string
2. Another function to add a custom shortcode to display the JWT data
3. An HTML to decode the JWT.

This is the aspect of all my code snippets for this trial:

[image: All code snippets]

This is not very clean-code. Most probably the place to set the JWT decoding would be also another function, but discovering how to filter a code snippet to be run only in one page was out of this investigation. So I decided quick and dirty to set an HTML content that would serve 2 purposes:

1. Be inserted ONLY in the page I wanted to test
2. Output some debugging information. This can (should!) be muted in production

Therefore moving this code to a "function code snippet" instead a "content code snippet" should be straigh forward.

Let's begin!

## Add the "token" query string

Create a "Function code snippet" and copy in the code named `adds-the-token-query-string.php` in this gist: https://gist.github.com/xmontero/d7fac0eaa13e5c913d1ea35e6a3ba01e

Name it [Adds the "token" query string] or something useful for you.

Mark it as "run everywhere".

[image: Snippet add token]

The code is very simple and just tells WordPress to be aware that a query parameter `token` could come in and therefore it should be taken on account.

Taken from this S.O. answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48930830/1315009

## Decoding the JWT

Now that we have the "conditional part" ready we go for the heavy part: Decoding the JWT.

Create a "Content code snippet" and copy in the code named `decode.jwt.content.php` in the same gist: https://gist.github.com/xmontero/d7fac0eaa13e5c913d1ea35e6a3ba01e

[image: Snippet decode JWT]

This code is a bit longer but it's very easy. The length of this code is why I used gist instead of inlining it in this answer.

The snippet mainly has 3 parts:

- Defines 2 functions: base64UrlEncode and base64UrlDecode which implement the URL-safe version of the base64 encoding.
- A large comment on how to create a token.
- The body itself of the snippet which renders the debugging in the decoding process.

### Decoding the JWT - 1) base64Url encoding

There's plenty of URLs pointing to wikipedia, PHP documentation, explanation pages, and so on, so no need to explain every sub-detail here. I set there in the gist the ones I used today.

### Decoding the JWT - 2) Generating a token

To generate a JWT we can use the online tool https://jwt.io

1. Here we choose the signature algorythm. For this example I choose a symmetric encoding HS256 instead of a private-public key system (RS256). Moving to a private-public key system should be straight forward from this example.
2. Then we set the data we want to carry into the token. It's any JSON object.
3. Finally we need to set the signature secret that only we will know, so nobody other than us can generate valid tokens to inject in our wordpress.
4. Nothing is sent to any server, all is computed in your browser, you'll be presented a "validly signed token" with your secret on the screen.

[image: Generating a JWT]

### Decoding the JWT - 3) Body for really decoding the token

Inside the body of the code snippet mainly we get the info from the query string.

The code first checks whether the "token" query variable is present or not. If present, it decodes the JWT by separating it into its three parts - header, payload, and signature. It then verifies the signature by computing the expected signature using the secret key and checking if it matches the actual signature in the token.

If the signature is valid, the payload data is decoded from base64 encoding and stored in a `$GLOBALS['jwt']` array. I do this so later we'll be able to "consume" the token data from other PHP snippets.

If there are any errors in the JWT, such as an invalid signature or missing parts, it throws an exception, which includes the error message. This code includes some debugging output to help us understand how the JWT is decoded, but this should be removed once the code is deployed to production.

I have only implemented the "happy path", ie: Either the token does NOT exist at all, or either it exists and is valid.

If it exists and it is invalid, the "content block" will be displayed but with no data. Those trials were to check the exercise was possible and clean-code should be used in production, so in case of exception maybe we should set some global variable to "token got but was invalid" so the other scripts know what to do in this case.

**Essentially if the token exists and is valid, it ends up in a global variable named $jwt.**

I prefer to set both the header and the payload in the variable. One never knows what will need in the future. If you prefer, store only the payload.

## Accessing the data in the JWT

Okey. Dirty that we do it while "showing content" instead of a "function" as it shoudl be, but we finally have the JWT decoded in a "global variable". Time to display portions of it.

To do so, I've created another mini-snippet that creates a new "short code" named `jwt` and able to handle one parameter: What we want to extract.

Open the snippets menu and create a new "Function code snippet". Copy-in the code from `adds-the-jwt-short-code.php` in the gist https://gist.github.com/xmontero/d7fac0eaa13e5c913d1ea35e6a3ba01e

[image: Adds the JWT short code snippet]

Name your snippet something like [Adds the JWT short code] or similar.

Mark it like "run everywhere".

Use it like this:

```
[jwt payload=color]
```

This prints out the claim "color" (claim in JWT means the key in the JSON object) in the payload.

Similarly we can print things in the header with, for instance:

```
[jwt header=typ]
```

Super easy, no?

NOTE: I've assumed happy path and believe that my token will contain only strings. If it contains objects inside the short-code code should be improved.

## WOW!! GOOD JOB!

We have all the pieces now:

- We are able to recognize a parameter named `token` in the query string thanks to the "Code Snippets" plugin.
- We have a visibility rule in place to use in our pages thanks to the "Block Visibility" plugin.
- We are able to decode the token (if present) and see the debugging of the process.
- We are able to print ut

Time to put all inside a single page!

Go and create a new page, like this:

[image: Sample page]

1. Paste the short code of the code snippet that decodes the JWT. You can get it from the snippet editor, once you've saved the first time. In this portion of the page you'll see the data. In production silence the `echo()`s and remove the header so it'll be "transparent" to the user.
2. Create a group that will contain anything to the user when the token is present. The "Block Visibility" by default works on containing blocs, not on final widgets like buttons or texts. Better wrap all in a group.
3. Create another group that will contain anything displayed when no token is present.
4. Set the visibility of the block. For block 2 -> requirement ALL of "token is present", for block 3 -> requirement NONE of "token is present".
5. Use the data in the token at your will. Any place that can contain text, formatted, colored, bolded, can print data from the JWT.

### Find the decoding code snippet short-code

[image: short code for decoding snippet]

Check Evaluate PHP code.
Then save and get the code by clicking the "copy" button.

### Set the visibility of the block

For block 2 (data to be shown if the token exists) select the block in the layout:

[image: select block 2]

Then in the right menu, select "block" and in the "visibility" section set "ALL" of "token exists":

[image: select ALL of token exists]

Then for block 3, select "NONE" of "token exists":

[image: select NONE of token exists]

## And et voilà!! Moment to test!!!

### Test 1 - No token

Save the page and load it.

Without token you should see this:

[image: Test 1]

1. Load the page with no token
2. The decoder sees there's no token
3. The content that is shown is the one intended for "no token".

### Test 2 - With token

Add `?token=xxxxxxxx` to the URL and press enter:

[image: Test 2 - URL]

You'll get a page like this one:

[image: Test 2 - Content]

1. The token decoder code snippet will print you the portions of the token, the calculated signature and the gotten signature and if they match.
2. The same snippet will pass both the header and the payload into PHP arrays and will store them in a global for later usage from other code snippets.
3. The block shown is the one corresponding to "token exists"
4. All the short codes we set before in the editor, of the style `[jwt section=key]` are now printed in their corresponding place respecting format and so on.

Done!

Improvements: If you pass a broken token (try it) it still displays the block "if the token exists". This is out of the scope of this trial. At least "the main goal is feasible" now use this as a stepping stone to the fine-tuned solution that fits your needs.

I guess this opens a whole new world of possibilities (for ex: Doing API calls for getting remote content only accessible to users with X token, without even creating a user in the system, etc.)

I'd love to hear about your use-cases and comments here in Stack Exchange or the gist itself.

Comment: Man...if only other people answered their own questions so well.  +1